# There is no pgsql driver in my Heroku server

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, driver, laravel

I'm about to deploy my Laravel app in Heroku but it seems like there is no pgsql driver in my server as shown

[image: in this]

How can I enable this driver? I don't know how to access php.ini in Heroku as well. I tried to use vi php.ini but the screen shows this command not found.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it says command not found; then you don't have `vi` installed!

Comment: so can I install by myself? or contact support is better?

Comment: Contact the Heroku people is what I'd suggest. Perhaps they don't have PGSQL support.

Comment: Thanks man. I've already contacted support and wait for reply. Anyway, I think they don't work in weekends.

Comment: Uh, this question should not be closed.  I also want to know how to enable pgsql support in heroku using Laravel 4?

Comment: This question should not be closed.